# Can't hide navigation when screen gets smaller

Tags: responsive-design, sass

I wan't to hide `nav` and made `img` slightly smaller when screen gets smaller then `750px`.

[Example Code](http://codepen.io/matjazmav/pen/XKXGPY?editors=1100)

**This doesn't work:**

```
@media (max-width: 750px)
    header#site-header
        a.logo
            img
                margin: 15px
                height: 25px 
        nav
            display: none
```

**And this does:**

```
@media (max-width: 750px)
    header#site-header
        .container
            a.logo
                img
                    margin: 15px
                    height: 25px 
            nav
                display: none
```

Comment: It is because the stylesheet before the media queries is overriding those styles. By specifying header .container .logo nav it makes a direct path and has higher priority. Do  that or just put !important.

Comment: I forked you codepen http://codepen.io/leonlaci/pen/NrxmWg?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks for explaining, did't know that :) you can write answer so I can close this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet before the media queries is overwriting those styles.
By specifying a direct path to the element it gets a higher priority and then it will work. Or you can just place !important to give it a higher priority.